# How to read error logs programmatically via EnterpriseLibrary?

Tags: c#, asp.net, error-handling, enterprise-library

I am using a C# application that is leveraging the Enterprise Library to log errors. How can I read the errors programmatically? I would like to populate a grid with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a look at [Microsoft Log Parser](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24659); it may be able to help depending on the output format of your LogEntry's.  It basically lets you query using a SQL like syntax a variety of data formats.

Another option would be look at the [LogParser](http://entlibcontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=LogParser41&referringTitle=Home) functionality from the [EntlibContrib Project](http://entlibcontrib.codeplex.com) which is more tailored for Enterprise Library.

Answer (score 0):

Enterprise Library handles writing log entries to logs, which can be written to many different types of log (event log, file, etc). So it depends *where* you're writing your log entries to.

If you are writing to the event log, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6b9a7h8(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: I was hoping the API would abstract that out (like the log writing but no log reading?). I am saving to a text file btw. Do I have to manually parse it?